# XSD: Sequence with some choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a sequence of different types, for some of them I want to ensure, that at most one of these element is used. Here are some examples: `<Synchronisation>` and `<Link>` may occure one time. There are Elements like `<TextBox>`, `<Label>`, `<CheckBox>`, etc. From these elements there is at most one allowed. Either `<TextBox>`, `<Label>` or `<CheckBox>`.

Valid XMLs:

```
<Property>
    <Synchronisation/>
</Property>

<Property>
    <Synchronisation/>
    <Link/>
</Property>

<Property>
    <Synchronisation/>
    <Link/>
    <TextBox/>
</Property>

<Property>
    <Synchronisation/>
    <Link/>
    <Label/>
</Property>
```

Invalid XML, as `<TextBox>` and `<Label>` occures.

```
<Property>
    <Synchronisation/>
    <Link/>
    <Label/>
    <TextBox/>
</Property>
```

I tried to do the xsd like this, but it does not work:

```
<xsd:complexType name="PropertyType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Synchronisation" type="SynchronisationType"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Links" type="LinksType"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="ElementType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ElementType">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="TextBox" type="TextBoxType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Label" type="TextBoxType"/>
        <xsd:element name="CheckBox" type="TextBoxType"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: In line 5 there is an error: `The 'ElementType' element is not declared".

Comment: Well, at first sight, it seems, that it is using `ref` instead of `type` as the others do...

Comment: When I use the `type` I have to use a `name`, too. And then the xml has to have a sub element, containting `Textbox`, `Label`or `CheckBox`.

Comment: `ref` references the named **element**, not a type... `name` has to be specified "if the parent element is the schema element", in which case `ref` cannot be used. (As per [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_element.asp))

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have an idea how to format an schema, that the xml files can be validated as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for the problem:

```
<xsd:complexType name="PropertyType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Synchronisation" type="SynchronisationType"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Links" type="LinksType"/>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TextBox" type="TextBoxType" /> 
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Label" type="LabelType" /> 
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckBox" type="CheckBoxType" /> 
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```